# Add external C# script to PowerShell script as source

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that uses `Add-Type` and for `-TypeDefinition` I would like to, instead of defining `$Source = @""@`, define `$Source = script.cs`.

Is this possible and if so how does one go about doing it?

```
$Source = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\script.cs -Raw

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies 'System', 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

Then I use whatever in C# script later on in the PS script. I do believe these are the only two important area right now

Comment: `$Source = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\script.cs -Raw` -- assuming "script.cs" is located in the same folder as the PoSh script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get-Content** can grab the contents a file and use it as a string. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2). For instance:

```
$Source = Get-Content -Path .\path\to\script.cs -Raw
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @zett42. I do need to ask, though, does this make the `Add-Type` redundant? I'm getting an error now saying `Add-Type : Cannot add type. The type name '...' already exists.`

Comment: Can you expand a little on how you're using Add-Type?

Comment: It doesn't make `Add-Type` redundant. Get-Content is just storing the contents of the file as a string. Double check that the type you are defining in the script doesn't already exist.

Comment: It works perfectly if I add it normally through `$Source = @"..."@`, but then raises this error when I use `Get-Content` instead. I can't figure out why

Comment: Have you tried using `Add-Type -Path <Path\to\script.cs>`?

Comment: Using `Add-Type -Path .\script.cs` raises that same error somehow. I'm so lost. There is only one use of `Add-Type` in the entire script and this is it

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. Turns out I needed to start a new PowerShell session. Thank you for your help.